# Cannot charge due to low battery temperature on Lenovo P780

Tags: battery, charging

My Lenovo P780 won't charge because the battery warning always pop up & says that charging is paused due battery's temperature is too low. I have checked the battery's temperature & it is around -20°C. I am just living in the Philippines and only got this when I went back to work in Vietnam.

Tried to warm up the phone, but the temperature is still -20°C. I can only charge the phone when it is "OFF" & it takes very long time to charge; 5 hours charging & the battery is charged up to 60% only. Why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like a temperature sensor may have gone awry, just to be clear: the temperature of the battery isn't actually -20 right?

Comment: yup, tried to warm up the phone & played more games just to keep battery warm, and can actually feel it is warm, but still indication is stucked @ -20 degC

Answer (score 2):

So what you have sounds like one of two things.

One, there is a software issue giving false readings off the temperature sensor. In order to diagnose this I would recommend installing a third party battery monitor which can monitor temperature. If this gives you a normal temperature you know its software and a factory reset should fix your problems. If it still is -20 than it could be hardware or just firmware level software.

Two, the temperature sensor could be broken or malfunctioning giving a false or default reading.

Either way if doesn't cause any problems a factory reset would either fix it or tell you what is wrong.

Let me know how it goes, I may have some other options for you if need be.

Comment: Tried to download 3 battery temp monitor apps but all of them gave the same -20°C. Have not trief the factory reset yet...

Comment: Yeah, your temperature sensor's busted. You will probably need to replace the battery.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue, I did factory reset and then it started charging just fine.

Answer (score -2):

Put Tape into the center battry switch, 2 should be ok but in centre put tape